Guy nearly gets sucked into propeller/fan
I was watching a movie about two or three years ago where the male protagonist was stuck in a boat and a woman was on land near some sort of rotating thing (either a propeller or fan) in the middle of a seaport and there was some reason why he couldn't escape. The boat was chopped up by the spinning thing, but the woman was able to get him out of it right as the rest of it went in rear-end first. The scene took place during the day under a cloudless sky.
Statistics:

Color
Year: 2008-2012
Language: English


This could be Indiana Jones: The Last Crusade. Seems to fit your description despite the date you supplied and a few clouds in the sky
(Poor quality - Skip to 2:40)




This is what I was thinking, too.
